# How can I save a Contour analysis as a dataset in Foundry?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-contour

How can I save the current values of the output of a Contour path as a snapshot dataset in Foundry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the results of your analysis as a dataset in Foundry by clicking `Save as Dataset` at the bottom of your Contour path. If the path already has an associated dataset, the dataset will appear at the bottom of your Contour path. Click `Update` to update that dataset with new logic or data. Note that if you change the logic in a Contour analysis, building a resulting dataset using Dataset-app or Data Lineage will not update the logic used to build the dataset. You must use the `Update` button to pick up logic changes. If you build through Dataset-app or Data Lineage, data updates will be picked up.